# How to apply filter on json column in loopback 3?

Tags: loopbackjs

I am trying to apply filter on a json column of table but unable to do so. My database is in Postgres. The data in the json column of a row is as following -

```
 {
    "1": {
        "new": "yes",
        "model": "2019"
    },
    "2": {
        "new": "yes",
        "model": "2015"
    },
    "3": {
        "new": "yes",
        "model": "2012"
    },
    "4": {
        "new": "no",
        "model": "2011"
    },
    "5": {
        "new": "yes",
        "model": "2012"
    }
 }
```

There are several rows with column having same data structure in the table.
I want to apply filter such that it returns corresponding row if a data is found inside the json data. 
For example, here I want to return all rows which has model "2015". How to frame such filter ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Did you refer to the "Where" filter examples in loopback docs - https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html.  I think your question is not clear enough to get an answer. Try to add some more info about your models, like I am assuming that you have properties named "new" and "model" in some table(model) but I am not sure what do you mean by "1","2"..

Answer (score 0):

In your case this filter should looks like this:

```
YourModel.find({where:{model:2015}})
```